# Group logs in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

Does log grouping exist in GitLab CI?

GitHub Actions uses `::group::` and `::endgroup::` to encapsulate logs into collapsible segments, which makes log review simpler.

```
::group::{section title}
{logs that should be grouped}
::endgroup::
```

Comment: HAve you checked out https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#custom-collapsible-sections

Answer (score 1):

Based on the https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#custom-collapsible-sections
the solution is to use:

```
- echo -e "\e[0Ksection_start:`date +%s`:my_first_section[collapsed=true]\r\e[0KHeader of the 1st collapsible section"
- echo 'this line should be hidden when collapsed'
- echo -e "\e[0Ksection_end:`date +%s`:my_first_section\r\e[0K"
```